# How to send objects to sequence activity properties in workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

I am developing a SharePoint sequence workflow. It is consisted of the main part and a sequence activity which I have implemented separately. I have used that sequence activity for one of the workflow nodes. This is the [approach described by Scott Hiller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx).

Basically, my workflow reads a list item and based on that it creates a bunch of workflow tasks. Let's assume that my workflow creates 5 tasks. I need to make my workflow mark the rest of the tasks to `Complete` once the first 3 tasks are completed by the user. I do not know how to get to the rest of the tasks in the sequence activity, i.e. I do not know how to reference them. I tried creating a property in the sequence activity which would store the workflow item, but it generates an error (I believe only simple types, DateTime and strings are allowed).

Comment: [I have never tried this], can't you save Task Id's in string with a separator like '|'

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the only solution I was able to come up with as well. Feel free to post your comment as answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: There you go! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boris,

You can put all the task Id's in string with a separator like '|'

Retrieve again by splitting...